# Verificar de onde veio o POST

Tags: php, post

Existe alguma forma de limitar o envio de formulários POST por terceiros ao meu site? Negar todos, tipo existe o cURL que faz isso como um robo, mas eu queria inibir, tem como?

Quando digo terceiros digo vindos de outro site nao sendo o meu.

Comment: Uma das maneiras é examinar a variável de servidor HTTP_REFERER, mas ela ainda pode ser forjada facilmente. Se você realmente precisa de proteção contra este tipo de envio, seria o caso de usar uma variável de sessão e um ID num campo escondido do formulário, o que limitaria o envio com aquele ID por um determinado tempo. Caso a pessoa demore demais no formulário real, basta apresentá-lo novamente, com novo ID oculto, mantendo os dados já preenchidos, e solicitando que o envio seja feito novamente.

Comment: Frameworks como o Laravel 5 limitam o tipo de acesso de cada página por get ou post, e caso haja um nível de permissão por usuário você ainda pode associar o nível de acesso a "post" por determinados usuários apenas, ou seja, apenas usuários logados com privilégios "x" pode dar post na página "y".

Comment: http://recaptcha.net

Comment: verificar o ip de onde veio a requisição não funcionaria? Limitar apenas para o ip do seu servidor

Comment: @Bacco boa idéia.. mas acho que ainda sim eles poderiam pegar esse id se analizasem o código a nao ser que ele tenha limitaçao de 'segundos' mesmo assim.. a resposta do Mastria me interessou, o IP também pode ser forjado?

Comment: Nao gosto muito da idéia de colocar captcha ou usar frameworks, ainda mais agora que estou no meio de um projeto extenso, teria que adequar tudo novamente, nem rola, mas obrigado!

Comment: @user3715916 o id seria diferente a cada sessão, além de mudar em pouco tempo. E poderia ser usado uma vez só cada um, não consigo imaginar que qualquer FW vá fazer muito melhor que isso. A vantagem de FW é estar pronto, mas se for só pra isso, eu acho melhor resolver com código próprio. Até por não precisar de muita coisa.

Comment: @Elaine qual é o propósito desse bloqueio? Está, por exemplo, tentando proteger um formulário de contato?

Comment: estou tentando proteger o flood/spam com um formulário, nao quero que terceiros a use @PeerBr

Comment: um captcha não necessitaria fazer drásticas mudanças.. apenas uma simples implementação

Comment: mas eu tb não gosto de captcha.. há outras formas de resolver, até porque no seu caso vc quer limitar para somente receber se provier do seu próprio server..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para qualquer medida sua, pense em duas economias: Primeiro, custo de não fazer nada (alto para um banco, baixo para um blog) vs. custo da medida (desenvolvimento, manutenção, atrito para usuários legítimos). Segundo, medidas aumentam o custo do atacante mais do que o custo para você e seus usuários. Segurança nunca é absoluta e sempre um compromisso.

## Limitar acesso automatizado/repetido (bots/spam)

Formulários são abusados por flooding de forma manual ou automatizada. Qualquer ataque será o mais parecido possível a uma solicitação legítima - o esforço do atacante dependerá da recompensa.

- Usar recaptcha etc.
- Bloquear sessão ou IP após x tentativas<sup>1</sup>
- Limitar envio a x tentativas/minuto por IP<sup>1</sup> ou para o site todo (que pode prejudicar usuários legítimos)
- Retornar um ID único que foi gerado ao exibir o formulário, válido por um único envio e por tempo limitado (a Wikipedia faz algo parecido. O atacante teria que recarregar o formulário, aumentando a carga do servidor)
- Criar um intervalo de pausa. Se seu form responde em 0.5s, um intervalo de 5s é tolerável para usuários e reduz o número de envios de 120/s para 12/s
- Necessitar uma resposta por e-mail
- Criar uma autenticação manual ("seu cadastro precisa ser autorizado pelo administrador").

## Limitar acesso de pessoas não previamente autenticadas

Lembre de que HTTP é `stateless`, sem estado. A princípio, cada chamada você recebe sem histórico prévio e precisa comprovar que já aprovou o emitente antes:

- Provar que o usuário foi autenticado previamente (ele fornece um cookie ou um attributo `POST` de uma sessão que existe no servidor - terceiros têm que advinhar ou roubar o ID de uma sessão ativa no servidor)
- Provar que ele visitou outro endereço antes (HTTP_REFERER - facilmente forjado)
- Provar que eles sabem certo segredo (endereço/senha/atributo no POST especial - pode vazar ou ser detectado facilmente).

## Limitar acesso de todos requests

- Banir sequencias de IPs (de infratores conhecidos, de fora da rede da empresa/do cliente, de certo país - pode ser forjado e atrapalha usuários legítimos acessando de um lugar incomum, como viajantes)
- Banir certos requests (p. ex. nunca receber POST).

<sup>1</sup>Tudo relacionado ao IP pode ser enganado por usar vários IPs, VPNs ou adquirir um IP novo.

Comment: O mais viável para mim seria `Provar que o usuário foi autenticado previamente (ele fornece um cookie ou um attributo POST de uma sessão que existe no servidor - mais seguro pois terceiros têm que advinhar ou roubar o ID de uma sessão ativa no servidor)` tem como falar mais sobre?

Comment: @Elaine uma ideia seria usar o captcha com sessão e combinado com ajax, assim não precisaria de autenticação, o usuário enviaria um POST, o sistema solicitaria o captcha, se for humano vai ter que digitar o código da imagem, após isto o usuário pode navegar e também pode adicionar um timer para expirar a sessão após 10 minutos de inatividade, assim terá que digitar o captcha novamente. Acho que assim fica mais rápido para o usuário que criar uma conta de acesso. Pela sugestão do captcha, considero esta uma das me possíveis melhores respostas aqui +1.

Comment: @Elaine Isso descreve o funcionamento da session em PHP. Você inicia com `session_start()` em qualquer request, e poderá usar `$_SESSION`. PHP cuidará do resto para você - para usar cookies, coloca `session.use_cookies = on` and `session.use_only_cookies = on` na php.ini. Veja que isso não resolve o problema de *quem* pode obter uma session! Normalmente, isso acontece após o usuário efetuar login.

Answer (score -1):

Algo efetivo é verificar o "dns reverse lookup".
No seu provedor de hospedagem, configure ou peça para que seja configurado o "dns reverse lookup" ou "dns reverso" em português.

Então sempre que receber um request (POST, GET), verifique o "dns reverse lookup" pelo IP.

No PHP há funções rede como gethostbyname, gethostbyaddr e dns_get_record com as quais poderá extrair os dados para auxiliar na "autenticação".

Note que o "dns reverse lookup" também pode ser burlado, portanto não confie 100% como se fosse uma solução absoluta.
No entanto, é muito mais seguro do que verificar somente o HTTP_REFERER.
O HTTP_REFERER é facimente manipulado, inclusive pelo CURL tem opção para tal.
Mas o dns reverso requer mudança na configuração do servidor que submete os dados.

Podemos dizer que 99.999% dos bots não tem condições para mudar o dns reverso dos servidores que utilizam porque, logisticamente, os bots tem como alvo milhões de servidores e precisariam ter modificar milhões de vezes o dns reverso dos servidores pelos quais executam seus scripts. É algo inviável devido ao alto custo.

Exemplo, se o seu site tem o endereço www.seu.site, defina o dns reverso para "www.seu.site".
Em servidor de hospedagem compartilhado normalmente não permite-se customizar, mas vc pode pedir para a empresa que administra o servidor, que ao menos configure o dns reverso para que seja retornado um nome válido. Geralmente fica algo como "endereço.provedor.hopedagem".

Comment: Se você sabe que o IP de uma pessoa corresponde a "NET Brasil" (que pode ser forjado por quem forja IP), qual é o benefício? Vide http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dns-avoid-double-reverse.html